# Android - NDK - C++ - cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'jlong *' (aka 'long long *')

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I asked a similar question about `char to jsstring` ... but now I have a problem with an `int to jlongArray`, which I just can't figure out :/

I get the following error:

```
Error:(290, 10) error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'jlong *' (aka 'long long *')
```

on this line:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_de_meetspot_ndktest_MainActivity_LoadPlayerA(JNIEnv *javaEnvironment, jobject self, jstring audioPath, jlongArray offsetAndLength) {
   const char* audio = javaEnvironment->GetStringUTFChars(audioPath, JNI_FALSE);
   int* params = javaEnvironment->GetLongArrayElements(offsetAndLength, JNI_FALSE);
   example->LoadPlayerA(audio, params);
}
```

this is the declaration:

```
void LoadPlayerA(const char *audioPath, int *params);
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: Don't forget to release the array when you're done with it -- use `ReleaseLongArrayElements`, or you will leak the memory. (Same for the string, but with `ReleaseStringUTFChars`.) Note also that `GetStringUtfChars` and `GetLongArrayElements` take pointers for their second argument, not booleans, though it doesn't strictly matter here because JNI_FALSE evaluates to zero, same as NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` in Java is [a signed 64-bit integer type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html). A C++ `int` on the other hand [is only defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) as being *"guaranteed to have a width of at least 16 bits"*.

Lets's assume that your `int`s are 32-bit (that's a very common scenario): so now you've got a pointer to a bunch of data where each element is 64 bits, and you're trying to pass that to a function that expects a pointer to 32-bit data. That's obviously not going to work, even if the compiler had allowed it.

Some options for you:

- Change `LoadPlayerA` to take a `jlong*` or `int64_t*` (and change any code in `LoadPlayerA` that relies on the incoming data being of type `int`).
- Change the Java code to pass the data as an `int[]` instead of a `long[]`, and change `LoadPlayerA` to take a `jint*` or `int32_t*`.
- Allocate an array/vector of type `int` in your JNI function and convert the data from `jlong` to `int` before passing it to `LoadPlayerA`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael :) ..

here is how i did it:

```
 jlong *longParams = javaEnvironment->GetLongArrayElements(params, JNI_FALSE);
   int arr[6];
   for (int n = 0; n < 6; n++) arr[n] = longParams[n];
   javaEnvironment->ReleaseLongArrayElements(params, longParams, JNI_ABORT);
```